# How to stop a thread when you exit Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote the following code:

**test.py**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import threading

class TextWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.thread1 = None
        self.thread2 = None
        self.stop_flag = True

    def printTime(self):
        print(time.time())

    def schedule(self,interval, f, wait=True):
        base_time = time.time()
        next_time = 0
        while not self.stop_flag:#接続を切るボタンが押されるまでループ
            self.thread2 = threading.Thread(target=f)
            self.thread2.start()
            if wait:
                self.thread2.join()
            next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
            time.sleep(next_time)

    def thread_start(self):
        self.stop_flag=False
        self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.schedule,args=(1.00/200, self.printTime, False))
        self.thread1.start()

    def thread_stop(self):
        if self.thread1:
            self.stop_flag=True
            self.thread1.join()
            self.thread1=None

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
TextWidget:

<TextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "thread_start"
            on_press: root.thread_start()
        Button:
            text: "thread_stop"
            on_press: root.thread_stop()
```

It works with the start button and stop button of the thread, but when I press the close button in the upper right corner of the window to end it, the thread continues to remain.

How can I close the window and close the thread at the same time?

The past questions seemed to be helpful, but the Widget class was not written, so I didn't know how to imitate it.

[How to run a Method on the exit of a kivy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501099/how-to-run-a-method-on-the-exit-of-a-kivy-app)

Comment: I think the method is there. Just implement the on request close segment with a call to your thread stop function. That should do it I think. Not very familiar with Kivy but it seems like a logical approach

Comment: If you add `daemon=True` to you `Thread` creation statements, then the `Thread` will be killed when the `App` is killed.

Comment: John Anderson, I worked fine that way. `self.thread1.setDaemon(True)`.Please post as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned by John above, a daemon thread runs without blocking the main program from quitting. So, if the main program is killed, the thread is also killed.

Refer [this](https://www.journaldev.com/16152/python-daemon-thread) for more details!