# Kivy shows an error when referring to a variable

Tags: python, kivy

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501099/how-to-run-a-method-on-the-exit-of-a-kivy-app) and tried to implement a close event for my app.

I wrote the following code in Kivy in Python.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<TextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size

        Button:
            text: "Test App"
""")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty 

class TextWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = 'test'

    def on_request_close(self, *args):
        print(self.text)

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        scn = TextWidget
        Window.bind(on_request_close=scn.on_request_close)
        return TextWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

When I quit the app,"on_request_close" function is executed, but for some reason the print(self.text) fails, resulting in an error.

The errors are as follows:

```
 AttributeError: 'WindowSDL' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the class itself instead of the TextWidget instance that has the `text` attribute.

You can do the binding within `TextWidget`'s `__init__` method to fix it (below) or you can access the instance by assigning it an id.

```py
class TextWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)
        self.text = 'test'

    def on_request_close(self,*args):
        app=self.text
        print(app)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextWidget()
```